Laplace's method for integral
Suppose we're trying to asymptotically evaluate an integral of form $$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{x}{y}+y}y^{\frac{x}{y}-y+1}x^{-\frac{x}{y}}dy.$$ We assume that $x$ tends to infinity. The main question is how can I transform this integral that it would be suitable for Laplace's (saddle point) method? I tried "putting" everything under exponent (under some variable changes like $y=u\sqrt{x}$, etc.) and finding the maximum, but I was not able to since there's no solution to the equation. I guess the only way is to dismiss some terms, but I don't want to weaken the approximation.

$x=e^{\ln x};y=e^{\ln y}$

okay, the function under exponent will be $f(y)=\frac{x}{y}+y+(\frac{x}{y}-y+1)ln (y)-\frac{x}{y}ln(x)$. If I understand we can't find the maximum of this function

is the max at one of the limits?

unfortunately, no

how is that possible? the max is either in the range or at the limits.

ouh, i understood your question. Maximum is in the range but we can't find the explicit formula of it since we get a transcendental equation

I wrote you something in the chat, but it disappeared. $x/y$ looks like a good bet, and maybe splitting into solvable peaked function times slowly changing function.

Thank you, I will try, but if you have some hints you can always tell them ;D

@user619894 again thank you, I struggled for some time, but as usual, it wasn't that hard. The function under exponent should be $f(y)=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x}{y}ln(\frac{y}{x})$ and everything seems fine
